# Alternative ways to prove an easy set relation

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I have a simple set relation, which is almost trivial to prove, but surprisingly, I can only prove it with an "indirect" method, which is bugging me:

Let the set $L$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $K=\left\{x-v|x \in L \right\} $ where $v\in L$. Let $z \notin L$. I want to show that $z-v \notin K$.

What I do is this: I assume that $z -v \in K$. Since there exists a bijection between $L$ and $K$ and each single member $x'$ of $K$ is generated exactly by a single member of $L$, $x'+v$. Then for $z-v$, $z$ should be a "generating" member of $L$, which contradicts with the fact $z \notin L$.

Now, is this proof true to begin with? If it is, is there a more direct method of proving that $z-v\notin K$? Only the above proof by contradiction method came to my mind, which uses the "bijection" relationship between $K$ and $L$ and I believe that there is a much more easy, even trivial proof there, but I don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making it a lot harder than necessary? I am assuming that $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Assume that $z\not\in L$ and for the sake of contradiction that $z-v\in K$. If $z-v\in K$ then for some $x\in L$ we have that

$$x-v=z-v.$$
Now in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can just add $v$ to both sides to derive $z=x$. However $x\in L$  but by assumption $x=z\not\in L$ so we have a contradiction and so we must have $z-v\not\in K$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very clear proof indeed.

Comment: It isn't really clever to be honest. Practise these 'simple' problems to improve your proof writing and logic *waits for someone to point out an error in my logic*

Comment: Well, I wouldn't ask it here normally, but it really frustrated me not being able to find a simpler proof. And besides, I am not from a mathematician background. No need to be so hard here.

Comment: I am not being hard; I just thought you were a maths student! Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I misread clear as clever!